# How to parse a string of version numbers in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a string containing a version number like **major.minor.patch.build** but I only want to keep **major.minor.patch** where each number can have 1-3 digits.
How can I do this in groovy?

Examples for a result:
`1.20.30.44 -> 1.20.30`
or
`1.21.1.1 -> 1.21.1`

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for provided examples.

```
def majorMinorPatchBuild = '1.20.30.44'
def majorMinorPatch
if (majorMinorPatchBuild.toList().count('.') < 3) {
    majorMinorPatch = majorMinorPatchBuild
} else {
    majorMinorPatch = majorMinorPatchBuild.split('\\.')[0..-2].join('.')
}
assert majorMinorPatch == '1.20.30'
```

Note, you'll have to implement some error handling if the input data will have some format deviations.

---

Test on more data:

```
[
        '1.2.3',
        '1.2.3.4',
        '11.22.33.44',
        '111.222.333.444'
].each {
    def majorMinorPatchBuild = it
    def majorMinorPatch
    if (majorMinorPatchBuild.toList().count('.') < 3) {
        majorMinorPatch = majorMinorPatchBuild
    } else {
        majorMinorPatch = majorMinorPatchBuild.split('\\.')[0..-2].join('.')
    }

    println("major.minor.patch: '$it' -> '$majorMinorPatch'")
}
```

Output:

```
major.minor.patch: '1.2.3' -> '1.2.3'
major.minor.patch: '1.2.3.4' -> '1.2.3'
major.minor.patch: '11.22.33.44' -> '11.22.33'
major.minor.patch: '111.222.333.444' -> '111.222.333'
```

Comment: Will this also work if the **build** is just one digit? or if the build number doesn't exist? (sometimes we have this case)

Comment: @easygainer could you please provide some not-valid data examples? 1) build number is an empty string. 2) build number is one digit. What should be expected for such cases? The original value without modifications?

Comment: @easygainer added update for this case.

Comment: Thanks 
Possible numbers could be:
a.) 1.2.3
b.) 1.2.3.4
c.) 11.22.33.44
d.) 111.222.333.444


the result should always contain only
a.) 1.2.3
b.) 1.2.3.4
c.) 11.22.33
d.) 111.222.333

Comment: `1.2.3` -> `1.2` is this expected ?

Comment: Current updated behavior: `1.2.3.4->1.2.3`, `1.2.3->1.2`, `1.2->1.2`, `1->1`, `''->''`

Comment: The initial version works like `1.2.3.4->1.2.3`, `1.2.3->1.2`, `1.2->1`

Comment: I would like to have always **major.minor.patch** and remove **.build**

Comment: The first implementation will remove everything after the last `.`.

Comment: @easygainer based on your input and output detailed examples, I've updated the post, see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

That should be essentially one-liners in Groovy. To start with 2:

```
String listBased = '1.20.30.44'.split( /\./ ).take 3 join '.'
String regexBased = '1.20.30.44'.replaceFirst( /(.+)\.[^.]+/, '$1' )

assert listBased == '1.20.30'
assert regexBased == '1.20.30'
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression returns the substring of an versionString before the last dot - and so results exactly what you have specified in your question:

```
versionString = '1.20.30.44'
println versionString[0..versionString.lastIndexOf('.')-1]
// => 1.20.30
```